# When will Opera support border-radius?

Tags: css, opera

Is there a release or any news on when they will support border-radius?

I heard that they have supported it in the past, with something like -o-border-radius, what happened to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, after Opera 10 (Presto 2.2). Look for it in the next version of Presto (2.3?).

Documentation: http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto23/css/properties/

Developer Comments: http://dev.opera.com/forums/topic/258986?t=1252795344&page=1#comment2936734

**EDIT:** Opera 10.5 (pre-beta) supports border-radius: http://labs.opera.com/downloads/

Comment: Saw that 10.5 uses Presto 2.5 which also supports css3 transitions and transforms. But yes, it is pre-beta.

Answer (score 0):

It never supported -o-border-radius: http://dev.opera.com/forums/topic/651612